# NSTableView - how to change string just before editing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a table of file names. I want the user to be able to change values but i want to allow changing only the name without its extension.

So, if there is a cell with the value filename.zip and the user start editing that cell i want him to be able to edit only the filename part without the .zip extension.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you should apply an `NSFormatter` to every cell of your table. `NSFormatter` lets you customize the output of the cells. You should read in the docs to understand it better, I haven't used one myself, but you could customize the output depending on the cell's state (if it's being edited or not). I'm a newbie myself ... so I'm not sure if this is the right solution, but I hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, i figured it out eventually.